# How can prove undefined type has only one value?

Tags: javascript, undefined

After reading [JavaScript Garden](http://javascriptgarden.info/#core.undefined), I took notes as below but is it possible prove number 2. Please validate & correct my other proofs also.

1. undefined is a type.
2. undefined type has only one
   value. that values is undefined.
3. There is a global variable called
   undefined
4. global undefined variable has
   default value undefined
5. global undefined variable is not
   a constant
6. undefined is not a keyword

Proof (tested in firebug console)

```
1. typeof undefined \\undefined 
 2. Need proof
 3. var name = undefined;  \\ global
    variable undefined is assigned to
    name
 4. alert(name); \\ undefined, that
    means undefined global variable has
    value undefined
 5. undefined = 'rajakvk';  \\ we can
    change value
 6. var undefined = 'rajakvk';  \\ no
    syntax error

var if = 'rajakvk';  \\ SyntaxError: missing variable name
```

Thanks http://w3fools.com/#what-should-be-done

Comment: I guess if undefined had any other value, it wouldn't be undefined.

Comment: @JohnP. Thanks. that is logical...

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it by looking at the language spec.  There is no test that you can run in an interpreter that will prove it.  Such a test would only be evidence that the interpreter is or is not conforming with the spec.  The spec is what defines "undefined."

Section 8.1 of the language spec says

> **8.1 The Undefined Type**
>
> The Undefined type has exactly one value, called
>   **undefined**. Any variable that has not
>   been assigned a value has the value
>   **undefined**.

And there is exactly one tyoe for which `typeof` will return `"undefined"`.  From section 11.4.3 of the spec:

Table 20 — typeof Operator Results

```
Type of val                                          Result
Undefined                                            "undefined"
Null                                                 "object"
Boolean                                              "boolean"
Number                                               "number"
String                                               "string"
Object (native and does not implement [[Call]])      "object"
Object (native or host and does implement [[Call]])  "function"
Object (host and does not implement [[Call]])        Implementation-defined except may not be "undefined", "boolean", "number", or "string".
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct proof is:

```
undefined = 1;
alert(typeof undefined !== 'undefined'); // need to be true
```

It need to be true, because you've changed the undefined variable value to anything different from undefined type.

Comment: ehr, but now typeof undefined is 'number', right? Funny stuff: try `undefined = [1,2,3,4,5]; alert(undefined[2]);`

Comment: also, what to make of : `var c=1; undefined = 1; alert(c === undefined); //=>true`

Comment: You're confusing the undefined value, that returned by the `void` operator as in `void 0`, with the value of the global variabled named `undefined`.